# How to create chart with two DataSeries with different labels?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, chart.js

I want to create a linear chart in ChartJS containing two DataSeries with different labels.

For example there are two datasets:

```
DataSet_1 = {'2020': 6, '2021': 8, '2022': 10}
DataSet_2 = {'2017': 5, '2019': 4, '2020': 9, '2022': 11}**
```

So labels (X axis) are `['2017', '2019', '2020', '2021', '2022']` - I can pass them always as a list, but I don't know how to use them in ChartJS script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is maybe not the most elegant solution, but you could:

1. Create the labels, by collecting them all together (removeing the duplicates using *a "set conversion"*)
2. Transform the datasets to define the value/position in the chart
3. set the property `spanGaps` to avoid gaps.

**Here a short demo with the provided data:**

```js
let DataSet_1 = {'2020': 6, '2021': 8, '2022': 10}
let DataSet_2 = {'2017': 5, '2019': 4, '2020': 9, '2022': 11}

// creates, lables, remove duplicates,
let labels =  [...new Set([ ...Object.keys(DataSet_1), ...Object.keys(DataSet_2) ])]
  .sort()

let converted_1 = labels.map( key => ({ x: key, y: DataSet_1[key]}));
let converted_2 = labels.map( key => ({ x: key, y: DataSet_2[key]}));

var options = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
        datasets: [{
            type: 'line',
            label: 'DataSet_1',
            data: converted_1
        }, {
            type: 'line',
            label: 'DataSet_2',
            data: converted_2,
        }],
        labels: labels
    },
    maintainAspectRatio: false,
    legend: { display: false },
    options: {
        spanGaps: true,
    }
}

const chart = document.getElementById('chart1')
new Chart(chart, options);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
<div style="width:500px;height:184px">
   <canvas id="chart1" width="500" height="184"></canvas>
<div>
```